# Вывод различных (неизоморфных) ориентаций изначально неоринтированного графа

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Есть ли алгоритм, позволяющий вывести все неизоморфные ориентации графа изначально неориентированного и работающий быстрее, чем простой перебор всех вариантов?

Comment: Даже просто проверить два графа на изоморфизм не умеют быстрее, чем за некоторую экспоненту. Если в практических целях - можно попробовать перебор всех вариантов с отсечениями или как-то воспользоваться специфической структурой графа, который возникает.

Comment: Граф никакой специфической структуры не имеет, потому что в данном случае задача теоритическая. 
Можно как-то отсекать варианты на этапе генерации этих вариантов при переборе?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что у вас есть граф с заданной структурой и вы просто хотите найти все способы расставить стрелочки на его рёбрах?

Comment: Граф задан матрицей смежности. И надо найти все неизоморфные способы расставить стрелочки на рёбрах.